# Application does not launch in simulator-Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am new to Xamarin and I am trying to run a sample(http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/Snake/) Xamarin application in Xamarin Studio. I see the emulator launch (and a "deployment succeeded" message in Xamarin Studio) but the application does not load. Before this, I have installed everything as per Xamarin's requirements. Can anyone help me to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue, I needed to unlock the device by swiping the padlock up.